# Do jquery function really chain?

Tags: jquery, chaining

I have been told that jquery functions can be chained to each other.

So I was wondering if this code:

```
if (cDiv.hasClass('step-dark-left'))
    cDiv.removeClass('step-dark-left').addClass('step-light-left');
```

Could be changed by removing the `if` like so:

```
cDiv.removeClass('step-dark-left').addClass('step-light-left');
```

So, if `.removeClass` fails, then `.addClass` wont execute?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: well, addClass was executed. i was wondering if it is by error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) will *not* fail if the element doesn't expose the `step-dark-left` class. It will just do nothing and return the jQuery object, therefore [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) will always be called.

So, you'll have to keep your `if` statement around, unless you can work the class check in the jQuery selector itself. For instance, if your `<div>` element has its `id` attribute set to `cDiv`:

```
$("#cDiv.step-dark-left").removeClass("step-dark-left")
                         .addClass("step-light-left");
```

That way, the jQuery object will be empty if the element doesn't expose the `step-dark-left` class to begin with, so both `removeClass()` and `addClass()` will end up doing nothing in that case.

Comment: yes, but wouldnt that make an overhead for looking up the divs?

Comment: @Dementic — don't prematurely optimize. Maybe using a `if` will be quicker, maybe using a specific selector will be quicker. It depends on the context, and it doesn't matter unless profiling shows that it is running too slowly.

Comment: @Dementic, that depends. Are you doing something else with `cDiv` apart from switching classes? If you do, then a `hasClass()` call in an `if` statement is probably the way to go, since in that case you won't include the class name in the jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code you write will work as in first example. jQuery is very well written library, and all methods always return the jquery object. So removeClass() method, if it doesn't find a 'step-dark-left' CSS-class, it just would do nothing and return the jquery object so next method in the chain will work.

Comment: i dont know why you were voted down, since you explained exactly what happens. maybe because no solution was attached to your answer.

Comment: its a pity, but question was not about a solution, just about how it works.

Comment: This answer is self-contradictory. It won't work as per the first example — `step-light-left` will be added whether or not `step-dark-left` was removed.

Comment: The question was: So, if .removeClass fails, then .addClass wont execute? And not about code example. May be the only cause of adding if statement was to make the .removeClass() method wont fail, so addClass() will success.

Answer (score -2):

Yes that will work. If step-dark-left cannot be found it will be just ignored.

Comment: Sorry Rogier, but that is not true, i also thought that, but the second command still executes.

Comment: i wish :D, try it on jsfiddler or any other enviroment.